# Action not being sent from component in EmberJS

Tags: javascript, ember.js

When I close a bootstrap modal, it doesn't send the action it should (in application js:)

application.hbs:

```
<li><a {{action "showSignInModal"}}>Sign In</a></li>
{{outlet}}
{{outlet 'modal'}}
```

bootstrap-modal.js:

```
this.$('.modal').modal().on('hidden.bs.modal', function() {
  alert("Closed");
  this.sendAction('removeModal');
}.bind(this));
```

routes/application.js:

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  actions: {
    showSignInModal: function() {
      this.render('components.signin-modal', {
        into: 'application',
        outlet: 'modal'
      });
    },
    removeModal: function(){
      alert("Working")
    }
    //...
  }
})
```

signin-modal.hbs:

```
{{#bootstrap-modal title="Sign In" ok='signin' okText="Signin"}}
<p>
  Please sign in. Thanks!
</p>
{{/bootstrap-modal}}
```

The "closed" alert shows, but the "working" alert doesn't.
(The signin modal is a component, with no actions defined, and is just a bootstrap-modal)

Comment: (How) are you passing your `removeModal` to your component that becomes a modal? Can you show your template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not passing your action name properly.

You need to be aware that the `sendAction` method will fail silently if it can't find the action name.

Make sure inside your template that contains the modal component, you pass a property with the action name you want to call:

```
{{#bootstrap-modal title="Sign In" ok='signin' okText="Signin" removeModal="removeModal"}}
```

You can read more about [Passing Actions to Components](http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.10.0/components/sending-actions-from-components-to-your-application/)

Answer (score 1):

Actions won't propagate like event bubbing

Wrap your bootstrap modal into a component and give it the removeModal action from the signin-modal to call.